# how can I set the location of a fxml file in javaFX?

Tags: javafx-8

I am new to `JavaFX`, and while I want to load a `fxml` file, I use the bellow codes.

```
FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/secondAttempt.fxml"));
```

I am curious about a new way for setting location. I don't like to use

```
Main.class.getResource("view/secondAttempt.fxml")
```

Is there any straightforward way for setting the location of this `fxml` file?
I am looking for a new solution that doesn't need memorizing so many information to use a `fxml` file. for example:

```
loader.setLocation("C:/view/secondAttempt.fxml"));
```

Comment: I have found a shorter way to load the `fxml` file. `loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("view/secondAttempt.fxml"))`. But I am looking for a shorter way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of load calls, just make a small utility function:

```
public class FXMLUtil {
   // loads an FXML file from a location relative to this class.
   public static <T> T load(String loc) throws IOException {
       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
       loader.setLocation(FXMLUtil.class.getResource(loc));
       return loader.load();
   }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
Parent content = FXMLUtil.load("view/secondAttemp‌​t.fxml");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.